# Activity.setResult(int) and Activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity

Does `Activity` keep the result after `Activity.setResult(int)` was invoked and device was rotated before pressing back button (Activity was recreated)?

It seems that `Activity` does not restore this kind of information. If that is a case, should I restore the result using a `Bundle` and invoke `setResult` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, yes. The result isn't returned until you call finish(). setResult() presumes that the Activity setting the result (call it Activity B) was started by a call to startActivityForResult() from another Activity (call it Activity A). The presumption is that Activity B will finish, resulting in an automatic return to Activity B.